# How to use rpc parse operations endpoint

Tags: transactions, rpc, operation

I am trying to query the RPC [parse operation endpoint](https://tezos.gitlab.io/master/api/rpc.html#post-block-id-helpers-parse-operations)

The RPC documentation only states that this endpoint `Parse operations` and I can't seem to find example of how to use it on the web.

What I am aim to do is basically reverse what the [forge endpoint](https://tezos.gitlab.io/master/api/rpc.html#post-block-id-helpers-forge-operations) does 
in order to get the JSON from an hex encoded operation.

Here are the step I am using to query the endpoint:

## Forge operation

Query:

```
POST
https://alphanet-node.tzscan.io/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/forge/operations
```

Body:

```
{
    "branch": "BLpcXF8ADJbGuyUKNv7TypXRd5rqnoPn3PMqJLNBeRSr4VFeUuK",
    "contents": [
        {
            "kind": "transaction",
            "source": "tz1NfEiS2uJsX43vowNjau5pdqg3Nvy8whvc",
            "destination": "KT1Ec3jNXyxyA54nezwcjGDRoutECJCQjpya",
            "fee": "1274",
            "counter": "86610",
            "gas_limit": "10100",
            "storage_limit": "0",
            "amount": "5060726"
        }
    ]
}
```

Response:

```
"92122a7e654cdff09e22a7be1b7d41bd279ffa197a0137e6fea0d3ed3ce95fc00800002122d44d997e158c36c60649d198c4175dad425efa09d2a405f44e00f6f0b40201420eaa410ac21addf427211cddd6115cba385a940000"
```

## Now trying to reverse the forge operation

Query:

```
https://alphanet-node.tzscan.io/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/parse/operations
```

Body:

```
{
    "operations": [
        {
            "data": "92122a7e654cdff09e22a7be1b7d41bd279ffa197a0137e6fea0d3ed3ce95fc00800002122d44d997e158c36c60649d198c4175dad425efa09d2a405f44e00f6f0b40201420eaa410ac21addf427211cddd6115cba385a940000",
            "branch": "BLpcXF8ADJbGuyUKNv7TypXRd5rqnoPn3PMqJLNBeRSr4VFeUuK"
        }
    ]
}
```

Response:

```
[
    {
        "kind": "branch",
        "id": "proto.003-PsddFKi3.operation.cannot_parse"
    }
]
```

Is the parse operation endpoint really doing what I expect?
If so how should this endpoint need to be queried to reverse the forge endpoint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that /parse/operations expects signed operations. You can just add 64 zero bytes to the end:

```
{
    "operations": [
        {
            "data": "0800002122d44d997e158c36c60649d198c4175dad425efa09d2a405f44e00f6f0b40201420eaa410ac21addf427211cddd6115cba385a94000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "branch": "BLpcXF8ADJbGuyUKNv7TypXRd5rqnoPn3PMqJLNBeRSr4VFeUuK"
        }
    ]
}
```

Be warned that if you trust the output of these RPCs, you are [trusting the node](https://medium.com/cryptium/blind-signature-attacks-on-tezos-a-reminder-of-do-not-trust-verify-cd981119ff7b).

Also notice that the "check_signature" option for /parse/operations has no effect, as you can see by setting it to true...

Comment: Could you give a complete example of this, doing a forge, sign, then parse? Even after adding the 0's, I still cannot get parse to work.

Comment: I guess the question + answer gives a complete example, I might expand the answer sometime later. Two quick checks: You added 128 zeros (= 64 zero bytes)? You stripped off the first 32 bytes (64 characters) from forge, which are the branch / block hash? (I failed to mention that in my answer.)

Comment: The above examples all deal with transfer operations and I was trying to decode an endorsement. They are a bit different. I was able to get it working after reading some other posts and ocaml code. Thanks

Comment: I think your `data` value might contain an odd number of hex characters. Could you verify that you can actually run this code again and update the answer if anything is missing? Also: Is this main net or a test net like Carthage net?